# Enviar valores de uma tag <H5> para uma variável no PHP

Tags: php, html5

Boa tarde galera,

Possuo algumas informações em uma código que estão sendo exibidas com a tag  dentro de um Echo, abaixo destas, possuo um campo para escrita livre, preciso enviar todos estes atributos mencionados em tags  mais o texto que será digitado no  para outra página em PHP que fará a inserção das informações no banco de dados, porém não sei como pegar essas informações com o PHP. Se puderem me dar uma luz, agradeço!

Segue o script

```
      try {
      $veiculo->buscar($placa);
      if ($veiculo->existe()) {
         //print_r($veiculo->dados());   
      echo "<div class='row'>
            <div class='span12' style='text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;'>
            <div class='form-group'>";
        echo "<h5>Placa: " . $veiculo->placa."</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Marca/Modelo: " .$veiculo->marca."</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Cor: " .$veiculo->cor."<h5>";
        echo "<h5>Ano: " .$veiculo->ano."</h5>";           
        echo "<h5>Chassi: " .$veiculo->chassi."</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Situação: " .$veiculo->situacao. "</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Estado: " .$veiculo->uf. "</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Município: " .$veiculo->municipio. "</h5>";
        echo "<h5>Mensagem:</h5>";
        echo "<textarea class='form-control' rows='5' id='comment'></textarea>";
      echo "</div>";                  
      echo"<a href='salvaComment.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Enviar Comentário</a>";
      echo"<a href='index.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Pesquise outra placa!</a>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</br>";
      echo "<h6 align='center'>Data e hora da pesquisa: ".$veiculo->data."</h6>";
      }
  }catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='span12' style='text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;'>";
    echo "<h5>".$e->getMessage()."</h5>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo"<a href='index.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Tente novamente!</a>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As informações que estao dentro do h5 vc ja tem elas pois vem do banco e voce usa a $veiculo, bastar pegar a placa e consultar no banco para pegar essas informações.

Mas se voce pretende mostrar essas informações para o usuario e deixar ele editar elas para serem salvas no banco, vc precisa colocar elas em:

```
     <input type="text" name="cor" value="<?php echo $veiculo->cor;?>">
```

Comment: Ainda não tenho essas informações no banco, como mencionei abaixo, eu busco esses dados em um link externo, preciso adicionar um comentário para só então salvar no banco.

Comment: Entao como ja foi falado, voce precisa colocar essas informações em input text e o comentario numa textarea, da para vc pegar as informações de dentro do <h5> com javascript mas no seu caso seria melhor mesmo montar um formulario e depois que o usuario digitar tudo que precisa enviar para voce salvar no banco

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa colocar o textarea dentro de um form e colocar um atributo name no textarea, exemplo `name="mensagem"`. Para pegar as informações vc deve utilizar por exemplo `$_POST['mensagem']`.

Comment: Sim, quanto ao textarea eu consigo pegá-lo no PHP fazendo o form, como você citou, porém também preciso dos valores dentro de cada tag <H5> (placa, marca, cor, etc...), pois no banco, os comentários serão atribuídos conforme os dados do carro...

Comment: Entendi, provavelmente o que vc precisa é só da placa, pois imagino que ela é a sua chave primária da tabela com as informações do veículo. Você pode colocar um input hidden com o atributo name a placa. Sendo assim para salvar o comentário, vc dá um Select na tabela pela placa e acrescenta o conteúdo do comentário.

Comment: Na realidade esses dados ainda não se encontram no banco, pois são buscados em um link externo, a função que consulta no link cria a classe veículos com base nos dados que estão no Host, só após ser informado o comentário que serão inseridos no banco, por isso queria pegar dentro do H5.

Comment: Faz algo parecido com:

<form action="salvaComment.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="placa" value="$veiculo->placa">
Continua pros outros dados como acima

</form>
No arquivo q vai receber os dados coloca:
<?php
echo "placa" . $_POST["placa"];

?>

Comment: Entendi, mostrar as informações dentro de um form mesmo, desta forma eu já havia feito. Porém, como estas informações serão somente para exibição, tinha optado pela tag H5 mais pelo visual e gostaria de saber se era possível capturar esses valores. Porém, vou repassar com o form mesmo, depois eu consigo o resultado visual que quero via CSS. Obrigado!